# Erro em retorno do get de delphi para php

Tags: php, json, delphi, get

Envio o seguinte get no php

```
http://site.com.br/Autenticacao/index.php?conteudo={"Login":"otacio@mail.com","Senha":"123","Posicao":{"Latitude":"-18.8693459","Longitude":"-41.955664"}}
```

E recebo

```
http://site.com.br/Autenticacao/index.php?Situcao=O&idCliente=714107-e72ca8-9aca93-0ec496-cc0e30
```

Enviei um json e retornei um get, mais mesmo retornando em json da o mesmo erro.

Ate ai roda blza, mais quando faço no delphi, retorna o seguinte erro

> HTTP/1.1.302.Moved Temporary

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma no delphi

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var     Urls  : string;
begin

   Urls := 'http://usebum.com.br/Autenticacao/index.php?conteudo={"Login":"otacio@mail.com","Senha":"123","Posicao":{"Latitude":"-18.8693459","Longitude":"-41.955664"}}';
   urls := IdHTTP1.Get(Urls);
end;
```

Estou usando o delphi 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta salvando a resposta em um StringStream.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var     Urls  : string;
    lResponse : TStringStream;
    begin
    lResponse := TStringStream.Create('');

    try
    urls := IdHTTP1.Get('http://usebum.com.br/Autenticacao/index.php?conteudo={"Login":"otacio@mail.com","Senha":"123","Posicao":{"Latitude":"-18.8693459","Longitude":"-41.955664"}}', lResponse);
    finally
    lResponse.Free();
end;
```

lResponse conterá o conteúdo da página

Comment: testei,nao deu erro,mais nao retorna nada,retorna vazio.

Comment: Estranho. Eu testei a URL da requisição aqui e também está retornando uma página em branco. Será que não é problema nesta página que recebe a requisição?

Comment: Deu certo era isso mesmo,o que estava quebrando e que gerava um redirecionamento no final do script,removi e foi. A sua tela em branca é porque removi o conteúdo teste. Obrigado pela sua dica.